# how to use monthNames in jqgrid when validating date?

Tags: validation, jqgrid

In my jqgrid when i am clicking on add new record i have date field prepopulated with current date. Format of the date is yyyy-MMM-d (e.g. 2010-Jan-23).
Date is required field and when i click submit button it fails validation and displays error that this date is invalid, and it wants Y-m-d format.

How can i check my value with jqgrid? In other words how to make jqgrid accept the following date format when validating 2010-Jan-23?

Thanks.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{"rows":[

{"id":1,"cell":["2010-Mar-3","Pepto","2","False","not active"]},
{"id":2,"cell":["2009-May-6","Tylenol","5","False","not active"]},
{"id":3,"cell":["2008-May-6","Aspirin","9","True","active"]}

]}},
```

Here is my date column definition:

```
{ name: 'Date', 
index: 'date', 
width: '80px', 
align: 'center', 
sortable: false,
editable: true, 
datefmt: 'Y-M-d', 
editoptions: { dataInit: function(elem) { $(elem).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-M-d' });},value: getDate } ,
editrules: { required: true, date:true} },
```

The getdate function inserts current date into field. here is the function:

```
 function getDate(){
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var now = new Date();
        return now.getFullYear() + "-" + monthNames[now.getMonth()] + "-" + now.getDate();
    }
```

Maybe this is because of this function? Can i insert current date from datepicker?

Amount of data sent from the server is not too big  (about 10-30 rows) and this application will be used by maximum of 50 people, so there is no concerns regarding amounts of data.

Anytime when i have value as 2010-Jun-23 in the field, i get error message:Enter valid date value - Y-M-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that you defined `datefmt: 'Y-M-d'` in the column definition of `colModel`. In the list of `editrules` options (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) is defined that if you use `date: true` as a `editrules` option, the validation will be done corresponds with the `datefmt` option.

Some more recommendations if you use date in jqGrid:

If you not yet use, think about of the usage of `jQuery.datepicker` (see http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats) inside of `dataInit` function of `editoptions` (like

```
editoptions: {
    dataInit : function (elem) {
        $(elem).datepicker();
    }
    // ...
}
```

in the simplest case). If you use searching for date fields, you can use `dataInit` with `jQuery.datepicker` also in `searchoptions` in the same way (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#colmodel_options). The usage of `jQuery.datepicker` in jqGrid is very easy, but it makes your program more comfortable.

Usage of standard date formatter (`formatter: 'date'`) can be useful to convert source data format send to jqGrid to the new format which will be displayed. For example,

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'y-m-d', newformat: 'Y-M-d' }
```

It is less interesting, but it can reduce a little the size of data send from server to client.

**UPDATED**: I must admit, I don't tested my suggestion with *exactly your* data format. Just now I tested all one more time and then read carefully jqGrid documentation about `datefmt` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options). For `datefmt` are only **numerical format for months** is supported! So the value at the time of date verification must be in a numerical format. What can we do? For example following

we define as parameters of `navGrid` function "add" parameters (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator parameter `prmAdd`) like following:

```
{ beforeCheckValues: function(posdata, formid, mode) {
      var data = posdata.Date;
      var dateParts = data.split("-");
      var mounth = dateParts[1];
      var mounths = $.jgrid.formatter.date.monthNames;
      var iMounth = -1;
      for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
          if (mounth === mounths[i]) {
              iMounth = i;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (iMounth !== -1) {
          posdata.Date = dateParts[0]+'-'+(iMounth+1)+'-'+dateParts[2];
      }
  },
  beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid) { 
      var data = postdata.Date;
      var dateParts = data.split("-");
      var mounths = $.jgrid.formatter.date.monthNames;
      postdata.Date = dateParts[0]+'-'+
                      $.jgrid.formatter.date.monthNames[dateParts[1]-1]+
                      '-'+dateParts[2];
      return [true,""];
  }
}
```

So we convert the `Date` field to the numerical format inside of `beforeCheckValues` function and then convert all back to the original format (like 2010-Jan-23) after usage of `checkDate`. It will work.

The main question is now: have we some advantage from such kind of the date checking? We can just **don't use** `editrules: { date:true }` and implement our own date checking inside of `beforeSubmit` function. If we find out the wrong date we should return `[false,"My error message"]` and our custom error message "My error message" will be displayed by jqGrid.

So the easiest solution of your problem we receive if we could change the date format to any numerical form (Y-mm-d, mm/d/Y or another one). Usage of `datepicker` will makes for users the format problem not very important. Think about this and choose the way which your prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much! You always have great answers!

Comment: For some reason it is not working for me, maybe because i already send data from the server in required format? how data should be formatted for using this?

Comment: Could you describe what is not works for you? Helps `datefmt: 'Y-M-d'` not and you receive error about invalid date format? Or you have problem with formatter? It would be good if you post code example with jqGrid and an example of JSON data send from server (at least one or two rows of data). Then we will find the error very quickly.

Comment: i have added datepicker to that field and i need to display calendar icon beside the textbox, but it is not showing up, what could be the reason?

Comment: If you have a problem you should post the corresponding JavaScript code. In your case you should just compare your code with the code from http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger and verify that you have image which you use for `buttonImage` parameter of `datepicker` (verify URL).

Comment: Thanks again for your great update. As soon as i get to work i'll try to do it as you suggested.
Regarding datepicker - i was reading topic on trirand forum http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/datepicker-imagebutton-not-appearing/  here - seems like you were actively participating there as well:)) and i got some ideas so i'll try it tomorrow. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue. I have resolved it using custom function for validation. I am suing date format as '23-Jan-05'. You may modify it to suit your required date format.

```
function datecheck(value, colname) {
            var dateParts = value.split("-");
            var datePart = dateParts[0];
            var mounth = dateParts[1];
            var yearPart = dateParts[2];

            var mounths = $.jgrid.formatter.date.monthNames;
            var monthPart = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (mounth === mounths[i]) {
                    monthPart = i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var dateText = monthPart + '-' + datePart + '-' + yearPart;
            var date = Date.parse(dateText);
            if (isNaN(date)) 
                return [false,"Invalid date. Format expected: dd-mmm-yy. (23-Jul-05)"];
            else 
            return [true,""];                  

        }
```

JQGrid column details:

```
colModel: [name: 'JoiningDate', align: "center", editable: true, 
           editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: datecheck },
           formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'y-m-d', newformat: 'd-M-y' }, edittype: 'text', editable: true,
           editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd-M-y' }); }, 200); } }
            },
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Abhilash