# jqgrid - use datepicker with dynamic colModel

Tags: php, ajax, jqgrid

I had a question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6629424/640030) about implementing datepicker with jqgrid. I think that question was too specific. I would like to know, has anyone been able to implement a datepicker with a dynamic jqGrid? The colModel, colNames, and in my case, data are generated server-side via an ajax request, then displayed locally. On the server, in PHP, I create an array with the colModel structure, then JSON encode it before sending it back to client. Valid JSON puts quotes around the keys, but according to examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041097/how-to-use-monthnames-in-jqgrid-when-validating-date/3041580#3041580), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6471087/640030), and (importantly) [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules), I'm not supposed to do that.

I tried to use regex to remove the quotes, but that just results in a javascript error because it can no longer parse the now-invalid JSON.

Is datepicker with dynamic colModel possible?

Here is the AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   datatype: "json",
   success: function(result){
    try{
     //alert(result);
     result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    }catch(err){
     alert("error in success json " + err);
     return;
    }
    var colN = result.colNames;
    var colM = result.colModelList;
    var colD = result.colDataList;
    grid.jqGrid({
     datatype: 'local',
     colNames:colN,  //column names
     colModel:colM,  //column options
     data:colD,      //table data
     editurl: 'clientArray',//changes are not sent to server
     cellEdit: true,
     cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    });
   }
  });
});
```

and an example colModel:

```
{
 "editable":true,
 "name":"date",
 "index":"date",
 "sorttype":"date",
 "editrules":{"date":true},
 "editoptions":{"dataInit":"initDateEdit"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171617/how-to-add-custom-formatter-for-jqgrid-with-dynamic-column-binding/5175127#5175127) answers. It should solve your problem.

Comment: still no luck. I'm using `var functionsMapping = {
 "initDateEdit": function(elem) {setTimeout(function() {$(elem).datepicker();},100);}
};` and `for (i=0;i<colM.length;i++) {
  cm = colM[i];
  if (cm.editoptions.hasOwnProperty("dataInit") && 
   functionsMapping.hasOwnProperty(cm.editoptions.dataInit)) {
   cm.editoptions = {dataInit: functionsMapping[cm.editoptions.dataInit]};
  }
 }`

Comment: setTimeout is what was ruining me.